# Changing the name of an exposed COM interop method name C#

Tags: c#, com

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the name of a method exposed to COM so that I can rename the real C# method name without breaking the exposed COM contract?

```
[ComVisible(true)]
class SomeClass
{
    [ComMethodName("ExposedMethodName")] // Is there an existing attribute for this purpose?
    void SomeMethodName()
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Sure.  Wrap the method in another method, decorate it with `[ComVisible(true)]` and give the new method any name you want.

Comment: One solution (but it may be too late) is to rely on IUnknown (not IDispatch) interfaces (like ISomeClass) that you'd implement in SomeClass. Your clients would reference these interfaces instead of the automatically generated interface that .NET will produce (with names like SomeMethodName). IUnknown interfaces names are irrelevant (only the interface IID, method index and signature is).

Comment: Thanks  Robert Harvey, this is excatly what I did, but I wanted to avoid this wrapper.

Comment: Thanks Simon Mourier, it is never too late to refactor some code ;) but the ugly point with your solution is "what happend if 2 methods have the same signature". Preferably, I prefer having an explicit method name.

Comment: No problem with two methods with the same signature in the same interface.  This is COM. You declare the two and implement the two. Like I said, the method index and signature count. There's no possible ambiguity

Comment: Hi - I want to do this exact thing but for a different reason. I want to override the way enums are exposed. Instead of MYENUM_value1 I want to expose it to COM as MYENUMvalue1. This is to allow legacy COM clients to use the .NET enum without needing to rebuild them :)